# How to bootstrap AutoMapper with Unity?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, automapper, ioc-container

I need to use `Unity` as my DI container and want to bootstrap `AutoMapper`.

Using `StructureMap` I can do it like this;

```
For<IMappingEngine>().Use(() => Mapper.Engine);
```

How do I do this in `Unity`?

I have used the Package Manager to get hold of the currently newest version of `AutoMapper` 2.2.1-ci9000, but could also use 2.2.0 in case that is simpler.  I use version 2.1.505.0 of `Microsoft.Practices.Unity`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IMappingEngine>(new InjectionFactory(_ => Mapper.Engine));
```